# Hyper-V not getting IP Address for PXE Booting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, pxe-boot

I'm trying to get a Windows installation happening within a Hyper-V machine from a WDS Server in a VM.
It's a bit of a confusing set up. I have my laptop which is running 2 VMs - One is Windows Server 2008 R2 (AD / DHCP / DNS), the second is Windows Server 2008 R2 running Windows Deployment Services. 
I then having a physical machine which is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V installed. They're all connected and communicating fine. They can all ping each other with no issues. Both the physical server and the WDS server are authenticated on the domain and logged in.
I have a physical NIC on the physical server that is connecting to my laptop via network cabling - which is how they all communicate.
Whenever I start up my Hyper-V machine to get it to retrieve an installation via the WDS server, nothing happens. The DHCP just times out. I've tried everything I can think of. The physical NIC in the physical server is a TP-Link TG-3468.
The NIC on the laptop is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller - RTL8167.
The adapter is set as a legacy adapter in the Hyper-V settings.
Why can't the Hyper-V pick up an IP address for PXE booting?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the cable from the physical server directly connected to your laptop, or running through a switch?

Comment: Direct. Straight from the NIC in the physical server to the NIC in my laptop.

Comment: Are any other devices able to get a DHCP address from the VM on your laptop?

Comment: Yes. The physical server can get an address via DHCP.

Comment: I've never used it, but I'm going to try an install Server 2012 R2 on another partition on the physical server. I've got nothing to lose.